# Listener not working with Modal Dialog

Tags: jdialog

My Intention - Create a frame, add a button. When clicked the button, a Modal Dialog appears with custom buttons and text fields. takes user input from this dialog. close the dialog and pass the value to frame controls.

Question - I successfully achieved this when I created a Modeless dialog, but this does not work with Modal dialog:

when used, modeless dialog, clicking OK button on dialog, passed the value to frame and closed the dialog. But when set the dialog to modal = true, OK button on dialog is not working

code I used:

```
JButton diabtn = new JButton("Dialog");
    diabtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

            final JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JFrame)null,"Dia Window",true); 



            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setSize(350,200);


            JLabel dialbl1 = new JLabel("Enter your name");
            JButton diaok = new JButton("OK");
            final JTextField diatxt = new JTextField(20);
            diaok.setSize(60,60);
            dialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            dialog.add(dialbl1);
            dialog.add(diatxt);
            dialog.add(diaok);
            dialog.setVisible(true);

// adding listener for button on the dialog

            diaok.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            String tempval = diatxt.getText();
            lblDialogValue.setText(tempval);
            dialog.dispose();

        }
        }); 

        }
        });
```

Comment: I got the solution for this issue now: I placed the code  dialog.setVisible(true); after the listener for the diaok button. It appears that once visibility is true, no code after that is executed, please tell if this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Java expert, but there is some corroboration for what you are saying: Code after the `.setvisible()` is only executed after the dialog is closed.  [See reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597643/jdialog-modal-problem-java-gui?rq=1).